# Apex - Generate all Possible Combination of a Name

Tags: salesforce, apex

i have to generate all possible Combination of a Name 'Tony Stark'.
Like noty, onty etc.
and after generating all possible Names Combination ,
We have to create Accounts for All Names Combination.
Thank You.

Comment: And? What have you tried, what are you stuck with? Wrote any code?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know that, if you get my solution in comment

You need to generate all possible combination on given String (or say Name) which means all rearrangement of the name letter of an ordered into a one-to-one correspondence.
A string of length n has n! permutation.

So I suggest you can go with two method:-

1. **Backtracking Algorithim** with **Time Complexity: O(n*n!)**
2. Or you can use substring method of Apex String with for Loop to get all the combination Time Complexity: O(n*n!)

Let me know if you have any other query on this, if you have written the code then you can also post here and I can look into that.

Thanks.